# Blazor Web Assembly with asp.net core hosted vs Blazor Server Project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I’m working on data migration project where we need to fetch data from legacy systems on premises or on cloud and then transform them and show readonly dataviews with filtering and search etc.

Note:- with no managed code on IIS

I’m bit confused about choosing Blazor hosting options, EITHER Blazor Server or Blazor web assembly with asp.net core hosted?

Please note that data is historical and we need good performance.

Thanks,

Comment: @HenkHolterman Yes you are right we need to have a server. But you can see that both options have server project included. I'm bit confused between choosing the most appropriate approach. As you can see that blazor web assembly also have a asp.net core hosted option, So I confused because I assume that if I use Blazor Web assembly with asp.net core hosted that includes both client and server project in that case I can implement Searching/Filtering , event handling on WASM and fetching data, API's and reading writing in database on Server Side.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only accessible from the intranet (or over a low latency network) go for Blazor server. Blazor server has several benefits over WASM in this situation:

1. Very fast loading time.
2. Much tighter EF Core implementation. A web assembly app cannot directly access the database. So there are serialization/deserialization costs and constraints involved, even if you are not going to use some other database access method.
3. Better control on security. On WASM, authentication/authorization happens only once. On Blazor server it can be enforced on a per request basis. Also, the overall implementation is much cleaner
   refer to this from Microsoft docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

4. In general, native WASM build times are long. So you will need some planning for your daily production releases.

Assuming low latency network, the only downside is the investment in the servers. But if the number of users is limited, you can experiment and find out the right amount of processing power you need to buy.

Comment: Thanks for the help for choosing the right approach. I'll go for the blazorserver.

Comment: Actually I'm very new to blazor and I was bit confuse between asp.net core hosted option and blazor server. As we need to fetch data from legacy systems and store them in SQL database(This job will be done by a scheduler). 

What I was thinking about WASM asp.net core hosted was that it may have better performance on Search/filtering data as events were implemented/handling on balzor.client side but to Fetch Data, Process it and Store it in SQL methods are implemented on Server Side. Please correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: That is how it should be on paper. But blazor WASM runs on mono IL which is not fully native. For native WASM there aren't enough benchmarks in this regard. In my personal experience (charting app with multiple charts of a few hundred points) Blazor server is faster. If you have doubts, you can do your own benchmarking. If you design it properly, you can easily switch between two models without code change.